# Build gerrit plugin

Tags: gerrit

I'm tring to build Gerrit LFS plugin and i'm get the folloing error:

```
user@gerrit-server:~/review_site$ bazel test plugins/lfs
WARNING: Invoking Bazel in batch mode since it is not invoked from within a workspace (below a directory having a WORKSPACE file).
ERROR: The 'test' command is only supported from within a workspace (below a directory having a WORKSPACE file).
```

When I touched WORKSPACE, I get:

```
ERROR: Skipping 'lfs': error loading package '': Label '//tools/bzl:js.bzl' is invalid because 'tools/bzl' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '//:tools/bzl/js.bzl'?
```

BTW, is there anyway to get Gerrit's plugin that allready build? (as .jar file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a large list of plugin on the official website at https://www.gerritcodereview.com/plugins.html

The **Plugin Matrix** table is automatically maintained by their CI. At the top of the table there are link to the CI jobs building a given branch.

Thus if you run Gerrit 3.6.x you would use the `stable-3.6` branch which leads to https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-stable-3.6/ , lookup for the LFS job and you will get a .jar there https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-stable-3.6/job/plugin-lfs-bazel-master-stable-3.6/

Gerrit comes with the *plugin manager* plugin built-in though it is not activated by default. See the documentation as to how you can enable it: https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/plugin-manager/+/refs/heads/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md . That should make it easy to install. (I don't know what are the security implication).

Answer (score 0):

1.You can download the lfs.jar file from this website: https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/search/?q=lfs
2.Upload the downloaded lfs.jar to gerrit_site/plugins
3.Clone All-Projects:
`git clone "ssh://user@gerrit:29418/All-Projects" && scp -p -P 29418 user@gerrit:hooks/commit-msg "All-Projects/.git/hooks/"`
4.Add lfs.config

`cd All-Projects/`
`vim lfs.config`
`[lfs "^.*"]`
`enabled = true`
`maxObjectSize = 100m`

`git add .`
`git commit -m`
`git push origin HEAD:refs/meta/config`

5.Restart gerrit and you can see lfs enabled true at the bottom of the All-Projects webpage[image: image.png]